# Calling methods of parent forms with swing

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JFrame form called `StaffListMain` which has the following code in one of the button click events:

```
private void btnManageLeaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Open the new form and pass the selected staff member
    ManageLeave manageLeaveForm = new ManageLeave(staff.getStaffAt(lstStaff.getSelectedIndex()));
    manageLeaveForm.setVisible(true);
}
```

The `StaffListMain` class also has a method call `writeToFile()`, one that I would like to use within other classes such as the one in the code snippet above (`ManageLeaveForm`).

Because of this, I need a way to call the methods of another form. Is this possible, or will I have to separate `writeToFile()` into another class and then use it in each individual class as I need it?

Comment: You're using NetBeans?  Please stop talking NetBeans and start talking Java (E.G. 'form' -> 'frame' or `JFrame`).

Answer (score 5):

You could pass a reference to the current instance into the ManageLeave instance by giving its constructor a StaffListMain field and passing `this` into that field. Then  you can call methods on the calling StaffListMain object from within the ManageLeave object if desired.